# Firebase Deploy problems using Switch and react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, components, stackblitz

I have an App and I can not deploy to Firebase when I add this line to the code:

```
 <Switch>
      <Route path='/:name' component={Business} />
 </Switch>
```

The data is rendering perfectly if I see it on my editor online Stackblitz or localhost, but I cannot deploy just because of that.

Here is the standard App code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Business from './pages/business';

function App() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/:name' component={Business} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I can deploy if I change the Switch and Route part to for example:

```
   <div>  
      <h4>Hello World!</h4>
      <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
   </div>
```

So I think must be an incompatibility with Firebase. Any Idea?

The Stackblitz panel stuck like the picture attached.[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: What do you mean by "i cannot deploy just because of that" ?
What output do you get from firebase-tools ?

Comment: I am doing it from Stackblitz editor.  I just uploaded a picture. It gets stuck on "firebase deploy".

Comment: If I delete  <Switch>      <Route path='/:name' component={Business} />     </Switch> It will deploy very fast .

Comment: Ok. Is there any additionnal output ?

Comment: Maybe Firebase Rejects the App for some Debug problem? I don't think so. I have attached the console output, but the deploy process does not output anything else.

Comment: Try to re-create the project locally and push it to firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve!  avoid using Stackblitz for deploying,